# Testing all possible permutation of user interaction using SpecFlow or any other framework

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, bdd, specflow

My set up is following:

- WPF client writting using MVVM pattern
- A set of unit tests
- A set of SpecFlow scenarious

When creating SpecFlow scenarios, I firstly draw a state machine diagram to see all the possible permutations of user interactions and the requirements to go from one state to another. Then I create a list of all possible scenarios.

For example:

- User presses Yes -> Uploads document -> Deletes document -> clicks
  submit
- User presses Yes -> Uploads document -> cliks submit
- User presses Yes -> clicks submit

This allows to make sure that we test all possible scenarios and don't miss any. However this is a tedious process and it becomes quite problematic if the requirements changes.

I wonder if there is a framework which could create your scenarios from your State machine, so if the step is deleted from the state machine it automatically recreates your scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really into generating test cases from a state machine, I'd suggest that you have a look into "Model Based Testing" tools.

In the .NET world, spec explorer allow you to do that: [SpecExplorer 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/271d0904-f178-4ce9-956b-d9bfa4902745/)

Answer (score 7):

BDD scenario tools are generally intended to enable, capture, and automate conversations between the development team and business stakeholders. What you're doing is testing.

Rather than using a BDD tool, I suggest writing your own, or looking for other people's work under "test framework" rather than under the BDD and SpecFlow tags.

BDD doesn't work well with exhaustive testing. Instead, it works best with a few scenarios that illustrate the behavior of the application. This helps the developers to be sure that they understand the business problem, and to show that their code supports the solution.

If you use a BDD tool for this, you'll start finding that the scenarios you create are really hard to maintain. English can't be refactored in the same way as code. Your state machine may even be better off under unit test (or a lower-level BDD tool - [I just use NUnit](http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/Example.PetShop.Behavior/Basket/BasketViewModelBehavior.cs)).